# rMBP - Keyboard + trackpad unresponsive at random, reboot fixes

Tags: keyboard, trackpad, macbook-pro

I've had this issue twice today and is troubling me a bit. As the title already summaries; without notice, the keyboard and trackpad seem to get unresponsive. The system is actually still running (seeing animations and other stuff still happening). The keyboard power button **does** actually work, pushing it will summon the screen to logout, restart or shutdown, but I can't actually hit any buttons (ofcourse). So I eventually hold down the power button to power down and then power up again, after this, the problem seems to be resolved.

I don't know if this would be a hardware or a software issue. And I'm wondering if someone knows this problem? I've updated my Macbook recently to 10.8.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got the exact same problem, I've contacted apple care and they are replacing with a new machine. they say it is a defective trackpad but it looks as though there are lots of people with the same problem.

Comment: I haven't experienced this anymore since my post. But did you also experience this on a rMBP? If I experience this again, I'll also contact Apple care. Will be the second time that I'll be sending this machine to repair...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a trackpad issue. I have the same problem. It has to do with USB. The trackpad and keyboard are USB devices. I often see the problem plugging in certain USB devices. It's somewhat random, but you can sometimes find USB kernel errors in the logs. I have a USB serial adapter that can cause the problem if I pull the adapter while it's actively in use.

By the way, external keyboards and mice still work after this happens. Also, remote desktop works, too. You can use these to shutdown cleanly.

Comment: Yes, and my bluetooth mouse also works when this happens.

Comment: I have noticed the same thing, specifically with a Dell 2412 monitor, where my keyboard and mice are connected.  Unplugging the USB cable from the rMBP *and* plugging it back in fixes the issue -- it's fixed when the USB is re-plugged in. (This is with a rMBP'14 running 10.10.5)

Comment: I use an HHKB (USB) and I get this error. I don't know if it's related, but I started having this issue once I started connecting the keyboard. I just uninstalled their drivers to see if it makes a difference.\